# Cannot import project.R in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I can't import my package-name .R in my android project.

Here is an image from my project. I've checked the manifest and every thing is OK.

[image]

Comment: See if there is an error somewhere in res.

Comment: No, there is not any error in res folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure all your XML layout file names are lower case, they should be file_name.xml or filename.xml but not fileName.xml
2. Make sure you have all resources in the res folder
3. Delete the import with R
4. Clean via Project->Clean
5. Check Build Automatically from Project->Build Automatically and let it build

If it still shows the error try restarting eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, It seems that there was some problems in my project version.